# Deserializar array de objetos C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Boa noite! Estou com o seguinte script em minha View:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var resposta = new Array();
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        $(".resposta").each(function () {
                var dados = new Array();
                dados[x] = $(this).children("input[name^='idQuestao']").serialize();
                dados[++x] = $(this).children("input[name^='idQuestionario']").serialize();
                dados[++x] = $(this).children("input[name^='idCampanha']").serialize();
                dados[++x] = $(this).children("input[name^='idFuncionario']").serialize();
                dados[++x] = $(this).find("input[name^='idOpcao']").serialize();

                if(dados[x] === "")
                {
                    dados[x] = $(this).find("select[name^='idOpcao']").serialize();
                }

                if(dados[x] === "")
                {
                    dados[x] = $(this).find("textarea[name^='descricao']").serialize();
                }

                resposta[y] = dados;
                x = 0;
                y++;
        });

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Questionario/Create/?questionario=' + JSON.stringify(resposta),
        success: function(result) {
        },
        error: function(result) {
        }
        });
    });
```

No meu Controller eu estou tentando receber da seguinte forma:

```
public ActionResult Create(string questionario)
        {
            try
            {
                var intermediateJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(questionario);
                var oPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<QuestionarioViewModel>>(intermediateJson);

                return View();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

e estou recebendo o seguinte erro: `"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '', line 1, position 1."`

Essa é a string que o controller está recebendo:

```
"[[\"idQuestao=1\",\"idQuestionario=1\",\"idCampanha=2\",\"idFuncionario=1\",\"descricao=teste\"],[\"idQuestao=2\",\"idQuestionario=1\",\"idCampanha=2\",\"idFuncionario=1\",\"descricao=teste\"],[\"idQuestao=3\",\"idQuestionario=1\",\"idCampanha=2\",\"idFuncionario=1\",\"idOpcao=2\"],[\"idQuestao=4\",\"idQuestionario=1\",\"idCampanha=2\",\"idFuncionario=1\",\"idOpcao=6\"],[\"idQuestao=5\",\"idQuestionario=1\",\"idCampanha=2\",\"idFuncionario=1\",\"idOpcao=11\"],[\"idQuestao=8\",\"idQuestionario=1\",\"idCampanha=2\",\"idFuncionario=1\",\"descricao=teste\"]]"
```

Já tentei várias formas, o que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Tente trocar os `[ & ]` por `{ & }`, pois no JSON, [ e ] não são caracteres válidos para chaves. Você pode usar o `X = X.Replace("[", "{").Replace("]", "}")` neste caso.

Comment: @T. Borges Se alguma resposta lhe foi útil, se puder marque-a como aceita `√`, assim quando outros usuários visualizarem sua questão verão que já tem uma resposta correta e aceita por você.

Answer (score 3):

Você esta enviando um array com array o formato do seu JSON esta ficando `[ [], [] ]` considerando este formato o JsonConvert espera que você faça o DeserializeObject para uma lista de lista, exemplo, `List<List<>>`.

Portanto se você fizer como no exemplo abaixo ele vai parar de dar o erro.

```
var intermediateJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(questionario);
```

Mas pelo que entendi do objetivo do seu código você não precisa destes 2 array, então poderia mandar só o array dados e converter direto para `List<QuestionarioViewModel>`

---

Porem acredito que tenha algumas melhorias que podem ser feitas para simplificar.

**Opção 1: Enviar o json como data no post e não por parâmetro na url**

Para deixar a função mais segura seria melhor enviar os parâmetros no data do post, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<script>
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();           

        ....

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { questionario: JSON.stringify(resposta) },
            url: '/Questionario/Create',
            success: function(result) {
            },
            error: function(result) {
            }
        });
    });     
</script>
```

**Opção 2: Serializar o Form e enviar inteiro**

Se a sua View e tipada como List e os inputs são gerados pelo Razor, você pode gerá-los como lista e no final só serializar o form e passar no post, recebendo direto no seu objeto. Para isso você precisa que a propriedade Name dos inputs crie uma sequencia ficando `name='[0].idQuestao'` por exemplo.

Para que isso aconteça sua view deve criar os inputs como no exemplo abaixo:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <div class='resposta'>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.i].idQuestao)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Itens[i].idOpcao)
    </div>
}
```

E o seu script ficaria assim:

```
<script>
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();           

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            url: '/Questionario/Create',
            success: function(result) {
            },
            error: function(result) {
            }
        });
    });     
</script>
```

E o controller assim:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(List<QuestionarioViewModel> respostas)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para facilitar a manutenção do código, recomendo que faça duas alterações, uma no controller e outra na view.

Na view, ao invés de serializar em formato de array coloque em um objeto, crie um modelo no c# para transitar os dados como por exemplo:

```
public class Resposta {
    public int IdQuestao {get;set;}
    public int IdQuestionario {get;set;}
    public int IdCampanha {get;set;}
    public int IdFuncionario {get;set;}
    public int IdOpcao {get;set;}
    public string Descricao {get;set;}
}
```

No controller altere o método para receber uma lista de Resposta

```
public ActionResult Create(List<Resposta> questionario)
{
    //Nesse momento você já deve possuir toda a lista populada
    try
    {
        return View();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Na view você deve fazer a seguinte alteração:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var resposta = new Array();
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var dados = [];
    $(".resposta").each(function () {
        var objResposta = {
            IdQuestao: $(this).children("input[name^='idQuestao']").val(),
            IdQuestionario: $(this).children("input[name^='idQuestionario']").val(),
            IdCampanha: $(this).children("input[name^='idCampanha']").val(),
            IdFuncionario: $(this).children("input[name^='idFuncionario']").val(),
            IdOpcao: $(this).find("input[name^='idOpcao']").val(),
            Descricao: $(this).find("textarea[name^='descricao']").val()
        }

        dados.push(objResposta);
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Questionario/Create',
        data: JSON.stringify(dados)
        success: function(result) {
        },
        error: function(result) {
        }
    });
});
```